# (libgdx/scene2d) Creating different stages with actors etc

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d, stage, scene2d

I'm fairly new to game programming and just started looking into building my first 2d game with libgdx. I've already build a stage with actors that are drawn to the screen with movement, pathfinding and so on. But I'm a bit confused when it comes to the usage of the class "Stage", when creating several stages.
Is the best solution just to create classes for every level that all extend Stage or is there no need for that, and the best solution is to have classes for each level and have a Stage-object in there? 
Hope this question isn't too confusing and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is necessary to extend `Stage`, holding one `Stage` as a reference and adding all `Actor`s to it should be enough.
Also you should not have 1 class for each level, you should have one class `Level`.
Then every level is an instance of the class `Level`, or even better, just have 1 instance of `Level` at a time, as you cannot play more then 1 `Level` at the same time.

So basicly you have a class `Level`, which is able to store all necessary informations, like all living `Mob`s, which could be subclasses of `Actor`, all `Block`s or `Wall`s (again subclasses of `Actor`) and so on.
Then the difference between level1 and level2 could be, that level1 contains 1 `Mob` only, while in level2 you have to fight 5 `Mob`s.
Also the `Level` could hold an instance of `Stage`, to which you add all the `Actor`s (`Mob`s, `Block`s, `Player`...).

You should also read the tutorials from the libgdx wiki, they can help a lot!

Hope it helps!